# Which is the better way to setup CSRF protection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

Adding this to BaseController.php:

```
public function __construct() {
    // Run the 'csrf' filter on all post, put, patch and delete requests.
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', ['on' => ['post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']]);
}
```

or adding this to routes.php:

```
Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete'));
```

Which is the better way and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both would have the same effect but the `Router::when` approach seems preferential.

It's quite easy to extend the wrong controller or overload `BaseController::__construct()` without a proper `parent::__construct()` call. In both scenarios no error would occur. If this happen by accident, you would have a silent security hole:

```
class FooController extends App\BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->initializeSomething() 
         // somebody forgot to call parent::__construct()
    }

    public function action()
    {
         // no CSRF protection here!
    }
}
```

Using the Router seems less error prone, there is no easy way to override the filter by accident later.

```
Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete'));
```

Comment: Note that the same may apply to auth filters.